# How can I debug a program when debugger fails

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, xcode, debugging

I am debugging an Iphone program with the simulator in xCode and I have one last issue to resolve but I need help resolving it for the following reason: when it happens the program goes into debugging mode but no errors appear (no BAD ACCESS appears) and it does not show where the code fails.  Putting some variables as global helps me to see their values to start pin pointing where the bug is but before I go into this fully I would like to know what techniques/tools you guys use to debug these situations.

If it helps Im debugging the following:  I merged some code into the SpeakHere demo. The code was added in the C++ modules of the program (AQRecorder.h and .mm).  I seem to have pinpointed  the problem code in a function I wrote.

Comment: [joke]  Debug the debugger, until you reach the bottom of the recursion stack.      Couldn't resist to inject a bit of humour in this otherwise frustrating situation ;-)

Comment: What's the nature of the problem you're debugging?  Am we to assume that you're getting an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when you run a release build of the program?

Comment: lol.....im starting to see where this is happening from variables state.  Im thinking of declaring a flag variable. At different steps in the bugged section of coded I would assign the flag variable a unique identifier.  this will enable me to see where the last "marker" was seen before the crash.  Finally I would add precison to the flags as I "seem" to be pinpointing

Comment: i've only ran in debug....but when I stop the debug run, the program stays in the iphone simulator and it doesnt give bad access it crashes and asks if I want to report the problem to apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My favourite is always to add debugging code and log it to a file. This allows me so report any and all information I need to resolve the issue if the debugger is not working properly.

I normally control the debugging code by use of a flag which I can manipulate at run time or by the command line.

Comment: If this is a memory retain/release issue it is unlikely to help resolve the problem.

Comment: Dave. How do you do that exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If the error is (and it probably is) a memory management issue, printing log entries is really not going to help.

I would reccomend learning how to use Instruments, and use its tools to track down the memory leak when it occurs rather than waiting until the application crashes later on.